# Difference between AutoPostBack=True and AutoPostBack=False?

Tags: asp.net, autopostback

What's the difference between `AutoPostBack=True` and `AutoPostBack=False`?

Answer (score 41):

Taken from http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/189-AutoPostBack-What-How-works.aspx:

> `Autopostback` is the mechanism by which the page will be posted 
>   back to the server automatically based on some events in the web controls. In some of the web controls, the property called auto post back, if set to true, will send the request to the server when an event happens in the control.
>
> Whenever we set the autopostback attribute to true on any of the controls, the .NET framework will automatically insert a few lines of code into the HTML generated to implement this functionality.
>
> 1. A JavaScript method with name __doPostBack (eventtarget, eventargument)
> 2. Two hidden variables with name __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT
> 3. OnChange JavaScript event to the control

Answer (score 15):

`AutoPostBack = true` permits control to post back to the server. It is associated with an Event.

Example:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="id" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectIndexChanged="..."/>
```

The aspx page with the above drop down list does not need an `asp:button` to do the post back. When you change an option in the drop down list, the page gets posted back to the server.

Default value of `AutoPostBack` on control is false.

Answer (score 10):

AutopostBack is a property which you assign to web controls if you want to post back the page when any event occurs at them.

You may see this article: [What is AutoPostBack?](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/189-AutoPostBack-What-How-works.aspx)

> Autopostback is the mechanism, by which the page will be posted  back
>   to the server automatically based on some events in the web controls.
>   In some of the web controls, the property called auto post back, which
>   if set to true, will send the request to the server when an event
>   happens in the control

For example, TextBox has [AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx) property

> Use the AutoPostBack property to specify whether an automatic postback
>   to the server will occur when the TextBox control loses focus.
>   Pressing the ENTER or the TAB key while in the TextBox control is the
>   most common way to change focus.

Answer (score 4):

The `AutoPostBack` property is used to set or return whether or not an automatic postback occurs when the user presses "ENTER" or "TAB" in the `TextBox` control.

If this property is set to `TRUE` the automatic postback is enabled, otherwise `FALSE`. The default is `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

There is one event which is default associate with any webcontrol. For example, in case of Button click event, in case of Check box CheckChangedEvent is there. So in case of AutoPostBack true these events are called by default and event handle at server side.

Answer (score 2):

**AutopostBack :**

AutopostBack is a property of the controls which **enables the post back** on the changes of the web control.

**Difference between AutopostBack=True and AutoPostBack=False:**

If the  **AutopostBack property is set to true**, a post back is sent immediately to the server

If the  **AutopostBack property is set to false**, then no post back occurs.

Answer (score 1):

AutoPostBack property:

Asp.net controls which cannot submit the Form (PostBack) on their own and
 hence ASP.Net has provided a feature using

```
 AutoPostBack = "true"
```

: which controls like DropDownList, CheckBoxList, RadioButtonList, etc. can perform PostBack(when clicked on it).

And

```
AutoPostBack = "false"
```

It is the by default state of controls which can perform Postback on button submit.

Answer (score 0):

**hai sir**

> There is one event which is default associate with any webcontrol.
>   For example, in case of Button click event, in case of Check box
>   CheckChangedEvent is there. So in case of AutoPostBack true these
>   events are called by default and event handle at server sid

Answer (score 0):

If you want a control to postback automatically when an event is raised, you need to set the *AutoPostBack* property of the control to *True*.