# RadioButtonList not firing SelectedIndexChanged every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadioButtonList with "Not Applicable", "Not Available", "Leave" and "Available" options.

1. I am throwing confirm message box on click of "Leave" in RadioButtonList from Server side as below

   ```
   protected void rdlUser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       radWindowManager.RadConfirm("Are you sure you want to take leave?", "confirmLeave" + this.ClientID, 300, 100, null, "");
   }
   ```
2. If user clicks "Cancel", then it will automatically selects "Available" with below code.

The following is the javascript code to "Ok" or "Cancel" leave.

```
    function confirmLeave<%=this.ClientID%>(arg) {
        if (arg == true) {
            alert("User has selected Leave.")
        }    
        else {
            var rdlUser = docment.getElementById("<%= rdlUser.ClientID %>");
            var radioButtons = rdlUser.getElementsByTagName('input');
            radioButtons[1].checked = true;
        }
    }
```

If the user clicks "Leave" for the 2nd time, the SelectedIndexChanged does not fire at all.

I am flexible to move Server Side code to Client side also.

**Update**

The following is the relevant HTML code

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser">
<tr>
    <td><span class="leave"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser" value="SLOT01" disabled="disabled" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser$0\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_0">Not Applicable</label></span></td>
    <td><span class="leave"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_1" class="Leave" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser" value="SLOT02" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser$1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_1">Not Available</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><span class="leave"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_2" class="Leave" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser" value="SLOT03" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser$2\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_2">Leave</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><span class="available"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_3" class="Available" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser" value="SLOT04" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_3">Available</label></span></td>
</tr>
```

**Update 2**

I am stuck here -- I need to point this.ClientID of RadioButtonList to $this of jQuery. Thats it. There by I can execute the 2nd Answer provided by @smoksnes

**Update 3**

If user selects "Not Available" or "Leave" then it should throw error message as "Do you want to take Leave?" and if he selects "Cancel", then the selection of RadioButtonList should point out to "Available". Otherwise it should select "Not Available" or "Leave" accordingly.

Comment: Probably because the radio button remains selected after the first click. This means that the second time the radio button value doesn't change. Try changing the value back to Available if the user does not confirm.

Comment: This is what I am doing right now `var rdlUser = docment.getElementById("<%= rdlUser.ClientID %>");
            var radioButtons = rdlUser.getElementsByTagName('input');
            radioButtons[1].checked = true;` in the else  part of confirmLeave.

Comment: Try using an event listener on the client instead of doing a postback. Something like this: `$('#<%=this.ClientID%>').change(function(){//code here});`

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate?

Comment: @CPK_2011 - Yes, I posted it as an answer since it was to long for a comment. Please tell me if I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're open to the idéa of moving the code to the client instead. Remove the `OnSelectedIndexChange` on your radiobutton to skip the postback. You should be able to do something like this instead:

```
// Put this in a script-tag.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#<%=this.ClientID%>').change(function(){
        var radioBtnId = this.id;
        radconfirm('Are you sure you want to take leave?', function(arg){
            if (arg == true) {
                alert("User has selected Leave.")
            }    
            else {
                var rdlUser = docment.getElementById(radioBtnId);
                var radioButtons = rdlUser.getElementsByTagName('input');
                radioButtons[1].checked = true;
            }
         }
        });
    });
})
```

Below is a snippet that uses id's without server code.

```js
$('#radio1').change(function(e){
  var radioBtnId = this.id;
  var $this = $(this);
  radconfirm('Are you sure you want to take leave?', function(arg){
    // Not really sure what you want to do here...
    if (arg == true) {
      alert("User has selected Leave.")
    }    
    else {
      // Select "Available instead".
      $this.siblings('input').prop('checked',true);
      
      // Unselect "Leave"
      
      // With javascript
      var rdlUser = document.getElementById(radioBtnId);              
      rdlUser.checked = false;
      
      // With jQuery
      $this.prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
    
// Mocked for now...
function radconfirm(value, callback){
  var result = confirm(value);
  callback(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1" value="Leave"/> <label for="radio1" >Leave</label>
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2" value="Available"/> <label for="radio2" >Available</label>
```

**UPDATE:**
I've updated the script to fit the new HTML. Here we bind the event to the monday control instead. Note that you might want to set a [`CssClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) on your control instead of using ID. Then you can use the same script for all your controls (MyMonday, MyTuesday etc). It would look something like this:

```
<asp:MyControl CssClass="day-control" runat="server" id="MyMondayControl" />
```

If so, you should be able to change the script below to start with:

```
$('.day-control input').change....
```

Otherwise you need to use the clientID.

```
$('#<% MyMondayControl.ClientID %> input').change ....
```

> Don't know why onclick="javascript:setTimeout" is getting added for
>   the HTML

That's because you are using server controls with [`AutoPostBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx) for your radiobuttons. Remove that and you should be fine. Read more about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173914/difference-betwwen-autopostback-true-and-autopostback-false).

In the snippet below I've taken the liberty to assign to CSS-classes to the different radiobuttons. One will determine when to run the "check if leave"-script. And one is for knowing which radiobutton to select if the user chooses to stay. The css classes are `leave-check` and `select-if-not-leave`. You can add them with the [`CssClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) property.

You might also want to check what HTML is rendered. The HTML you provided is using `table` with `tr`, so just make sure that the css-class is actually rendered on the `input`. Otherwise you will need to adjust the selector.

```js
// Change to the id of the table instead. Something like:
// $('#<% MyMondayControl.ClientID %> input').change ....

// Here I just the ID generated in the HTML, but you shouldn't use that one.
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser span.leave input').change(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var radioBtnId = this.id;
  var $this = $(this);
  radconfirm('Are you sure you want to take leave?', function(arg){
    // Not really sure what you want to do here...
    if (arg == true) {
      alert("User has selected Leave.")
    }    
    else {
      // Select "Available instead".
      // Here we use the css class "select-if-not-leave" to find the element which should be selected if the user decides to stay.
      var $parent = $this.closest('table') // Get the table. 
      
      // Select the available input.
      $parent.find('span.available input').prop('checked',true);
      
      // Unselect "Leave" With javascript
      var rdlUser = document.getElementById(radioBtnId);              
      rdlUser.checked = false;
      
      // Unselect "Leave" With jQuery (You only need one)
      $this.prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
    
// Mocked for now...
function radconfirm(value, callback){
  var result = confirm(value);
  callback(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser">
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span class="leave"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser" value="SLOT01" disabled="disabled"  /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_0">Not Applicable</label></span></td>
    <td><span class="leave"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_1" class="Leave" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser" value="SLOT02" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_1">Not Available</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><span class="leave"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_2" class="Leave" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser" value="SLOT03"/><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_2">Leave</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><span class="available"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_3" class="Available" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyUser$MyMonday$rdlUser" value="SLOT04" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday_rdlUser_3">Available</label></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

> 1. When I write jQuery script in Day UserControl, then I can use only .leave and .available classes but not .day-control. 2. When I write
>      the jQuery script in UserControl where MyMonday, MyTuesday,...
>      MyFriday are declared, then I can use only .day-control but not .leave
>      and .available classes. @smoksnes Please address this ambiguity.

Where you put you script does not matter, as long as the script looks the same. Preferably, you should put it in a js-file together with your other scripts. Here's a little info how the script and [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) works:

If you use `.day-control span.available input` it will first look for a some element with the [css class](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) `day-control`, and a element that is a `span` WITH css-class `available`, and lastly an `input` under the `span`. If there are several elements that fulfills the criterias I just mentioned it will return all these elements. This script should only be *rendered once*, since it will capture the events for all your `DayUserControl`, since they all share the same css class `day-control`.

However, if you use `#<%=this.ClientID%> span.leave input` it will start by looking for the element with the [specific id](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (`this.ClientID`) and there should be only one of those. That is why you need to render that particular script *once for every* `DayUserControl`, since it will be unique for that specific user control.

Comment: Some plain tweaking is required in your code. If the user selects Leave, then only confirm message box is required and on click of cancel, it should select "Available" otherwise it should be "Leave". And now for the second time it should repeat the same thing.

Comment: I have 2 constraints here. 1. I am populating rdlUser items, "Leave" and "Availability" from database. 2. I am using this rdlUser in an UserControl. The change needs to be done in UserControl.

Comment: The change event is not firing at all for the first code snippet provided by you due to '#<%=this.ClientID%>'. Some change is required in this. And for 2nd code snippet, I am having 4 RadioButton items. "Leave", "Availability", "Availability1" and "Availability2". This also does not work in actual scenario.

Comment: Yes, some changes must certainly be made due to the new conditions you presented. It may be a problem to use this.ClientID. I used it because you currently used it in your code, but you can just as well use a css-class instead. Also, you will have to alter the code a little bit if you want something special to happen with `Availability1` etc.

Comment: Your 2nd Answer of implementing all the code at client side does not go well with me. It works here with "Run code snippet". But I need to catch the change event the right way. Can you revisit my question again.  I am firing `rdlUser_SelectedIndexChanged` from server side and catching it the right way in javascript. I am trying to put `$this.siblings('input').prop('checked', true);            var rdlAvailability = document.getElementById(radioBtnId);            rdlAvailability.checked = false; $this.prop('checked', false);` in else part. But this does not work. Need a new/modified route.

Comment: Could you present some code to reproduce the issue? Without the server side code.

Comment: Could you update your question with the relevant HTML?

Comment: Updated the question with the relevant HTML.

Comment: I am having 5 UserControls (MyMonday, MyTuesday.. MyFriday) placed in 1 UserControl MyUser and this UserControl is placed in an aspx page. For current scenario, I have provided only for MyMonday. And for each day, it contains 4 slots of RadioButtonList called as "SLOT0", "SLOT01", "SLOT03" and "SLOT04" and the same is provided  in the question.

Comment: Don't know why `onclick="javascript:setTimeout"` is getting added for the HTML.

Comment: I have modified the question as well as your answer for clarity purpose. For `.leave-check`, I used `.Leave` and for `select-if-not-leave` as `.Available` After this the following is not firing at all.`$("#<%= MyMonday.ClientID %> input.Leave").change(function (e) {` The generated HTML is `$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyUser_MyMonday input.Leave").change(function (e) {`. I am stuck here right now
`

Comment: Please check Update 3 in Question.

Comment: @CPK_2011 - I've updated the snippet again. CSS selectors are case sensitive, and if you change the css class in your HTML, you need to change them in the javascript as well.

Comment: For me the change event is not firing for this code `$("#<%= MyMonday.ClientID %>_rdlUser input.leave").change(function (e) {`

Comment: But the snippet works? Check the changes I made in my last edit. CssClass should now be ´leave` - case-sensitive.

Comment: The snippet works because the classes `leave` and `available` are placed in input tags. For me the `rdlUser` is populated from database. From code-behind, I am applying the classes `leave` and `available` to `rdlUser` using the `foreach` loop. So, automatically `span` element got added. Could you please change the code accordingly.

Comment: Well, that changes it a bit. I've updated the answer for the new HTML you presented.

Comment: Now it is firing repeatedly for 4 times. I am not sure whether it is for `MyMonday, MyTuesday...MyFriday` or for `rdlUser_0, rdlUser_1,..rdlUser_3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126153/discussion-between-smoksnes-and-cpk-2011).

Comment: 1. When I write jQuery script in Day UserControl, then I can use only .leave and .available classes but not .day-control. 2. When I write the jQuery script in UserControl where MyMonday, MyTuesday,... MyFriday are declared, then I can use only .day-control but not .leave and .available classes. @smoksnes Please address this ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Pass caller object to radconfirm function.(http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/alert,-confirm,-prompt-dialogs/radconfirm-dialog).

Pass caller object from server

`protected void rdlUser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//var oConfirm = radconfirm(text, callBackFn, oWidth, oHeight, callerObj, oTitle, imgUrl);
    radWindowManager.RadConfirm("Are you sure you want to take leave?", "confirmLeave", 300, 100, null, "");
}`

One javascript function to validate all controls in a list.

`function confirmLeave(arg) {
        if (arg == true) {
            alert("User has selected Leave.")
        }

        else {
            //get callerid and validate
            var rdlUser = docment.getElementById("<%= rdlUser.ClientID %>");
            var radioButtons = rdlUser.getElementsByTagName('input');
            radioButtons[1].checked = true;
        }
    }`

I referred documentation and I didn't test this code hope this helps.