# how to do not postback button click

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to prevent this phenomenon ...

Postback when button is clicked

I want to perform the result when the button is clicked and prevent the screen refresh.

```html
<asp:Button ID="DomainSeachButton" runat="server" Text="search" 
            OnClick="btnDomainSearch_Click" OnClientClick="onMySearch();" Width="69px" />
```

```js
function onMySearch() {
    // __doPostBack("DomainSeachButton", "client");
    var r = confirm("Press a button!")
    if (r==true)
    {
         alert("You pressed OK!")
         return true;
    }
```

```cs
protected void btnDomainSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (_cDBConnect.IsValidDBInfo() == true)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("select * from tb_licensekey_storages where cert_domain_name like '%{0}%';", txtSearchDomain.Text.Trim());

        var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, _cDBConnect.GetConnectionString());

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);
        gridViewDBInfo.DataSource = dt;
        gridViewDBInfo.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `asp:Button` or `input type=submit`.

Comment: What does it mean? 
Do you mean to use only "button" or "submit"?

Comment: Everything is wrapped with a form (hence the name webforms). So any button, linkbutton, submit will trigger a form post (postback)

Comment: But how use kind of button??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with ASP Control UpdatePanel it will not actually refresh the whole page but the the selected content of the page, for example:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtpnl" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button
      ID="DomainSeachButton"
      runat="server"
      Text="search"
      OnClick="btnDomainSearch_Click"
      OnClientClick="onMySearch();"
      Width="69px"
      AutoPostBack="true"
    />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DomainSeachButton" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Should UpdatePanel and AutoPostBack be used at the same time?

Single use of "AutoPostBack = false" Postback happened.
ex) `<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button22222222" AutoPostBack="fasle" ></asp:Button>`

but 
Postback did not occur when using UpdatePanel and AutoPostBack = false.

Comment: Yeah when you postback set to true it refresh the content area not the whole page, otherwise nothing will change.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your btnDomainSearch_Click to

```
$("#btnDomainSearch_Click").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Whatever
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AutoPostBack="false"` in the particular button.

if `AutoPostBack` set `false` it will not send request to server otherwise it will send request to server.

```
<asp:Button ID="DomainSeachButton" runat="server" Text="search" AutoPostBack="false" OnClick="btnDomainSearch_Click" OnClientClick="onMySearch();" Width="69px" />
```

Please read this article for more information [More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173914/difference-between-autopostback-true-and-autopostback-false)

Comment: Postback occurred when using AutoPostBack = "false".

When UpdatePanel and AutoPostBack = "false" were used, postback did not happen.


but your comment thx