# How to disable a checkbox if another checkbox is enabled?

Tags: c#, html, checkbox, webforms

My web-page have two check-boxes and What I want is:

- Initially both check-boxes are unchecked.
- if  Checkbox1 is checked, Checkbox2 should becomes disabled.
- if Checkbox2 is unchecked again, Checkbox2 should becomes enabled again.
- and vice versa.

Please help me in modifying my code.

Here is my code:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //this.CheckBox1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(CheckBox1_CheckedChanged1);
    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        CheckBox2.Enabled = false;
}

protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox2.Checked)
        CheckBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

HTML

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Height="33px" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged1" Font-Bold="True" style="margin-left: 33px" Text="Remove Blank Lines" TextAlign="Left" Width="162px" />


<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Height="33px" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged2" style="margin-left: 28px" Text="Add Prefix/ Suffix to Blank Lines" TextAlign="Left" Width="259px" />
```

Comment: Why dont just use a radio button  ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
CheckBox2.Enabled = !CheckBox1.Checked;
```

Comment: @Emmy, I think you have to write above condition for `CheckBox1` also like => `CheckBox1.Enabled = !CheckBox2.Checked;` in `CheckBox2_CheckedChanged2` event handler.

Comment: Probably @Emmy assumes this is client-side code while it is actually server-side code that either requires `AutoPostBack="true"` or a submit button. Maybe provide a client-side-only solution, too?

Answer (score 0):

This answer for clarification to the new contributor

Add The [AutoPostBack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12173914/4977870) property to each checkbox control

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" Height="33px"  Font-Bold="True" style="margin-left: 33px"  Text="Remove Blank Lines" TextAlign="Left" Width="162px" />


<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" Font-Bold="True" Height="33px"  style="margin-left: 28px"   Text="Add Prefix/ Suffix to Blank Lines" TextAlign="Left" Width="259px" />
```

then in code-behind

create one event `CheckBox_CheckedChanged` and point each `checkbox` at it:

```
protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     CheckBox1.Enabled = !CheckBox2.Checked;
     CheckBox2.Enabled = !CheckBox1.Checked;
  }
```